# generating an email with the shared link

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, onedrive

I would like to share the skydrive link through email but I don't know how to go about it. I want to get the link after I have uploaded my folders and send it as an email. Can anybody help me? Some code reference would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Where are you having a problem, getting the link or sending the email?  What have you tried?

Comment: I have a problem with getting the link and putting it into the email. Can you help me with it please? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

have a look at this blogpost. I used it when i was adding skydrive support to my app - cool camera.
http://babaandthepigman.wordpress.com/2012/01/18/wp7-skydrive-upload/

this will get you started. Once you are there, have a look at skydrive samples etc
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826550.aspx#csharp

and methods exposed by LiveConnectClient
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/microsoft.live.liveconnectclient.aspx

in a summary, you upload, share, get url and use EmailComposeTask to send it